# What is this purple flower growing in Malaysia?

Tags: identification, flowers

I nonchalantly took a picture of this unknown flower and decided to post on a blog about it. Can anyone tell me about it, including the scientific name? It's growing in Malaysia.

[image: Here's the picture] [image: another one]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its Ruellia simplex, probably the variety 'Purple Showers' or something similar. Commonly known as Mexican Petunia, its a perennial in warmer regions and flowers for many months of the year. Considered invasive in some regions, more info in links below

http://www.hgtvgardens.com/flowers-and-plants/growing-mexican-petunias

The next one is more of a chatty blog type link about these plants in general:

http://www.jaycjayc.com/ruellia-simplex-mexican-petunia/

Comment: Im living in Asia,more specifically Malaysia,is it possible for this kind of plant grow?

Comment: Yes, because it is growing there, you've got the pic to prove it! I  jest, it can be grown as an annual in cooler countries anyway, and it doesn't look, from the pic, as if its growing in the wild as such... not sure what zone Malaysia is, but my impression is its a warm country, tropical or sub tropical, but I could be wrong...

Answer (score 1):

[image: Purple Mexican Petunia[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RaHR.jpg) Pink Petunia. [![White Petunia][3]][3]Mexican Petunia can grow wild. It can be propagated by stem cutting. In my garden they grow wild especially the pruple species; there are three colours: purple, pink and white.

Comment: See all 3 colours of Mexican Petunia in my FB posting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is also known as morning glory as it fades without sun light. Grows wildly in India near ponds and very invasive. In the blooming season hundreds of flowers together look wonderful. It has a beautiful dwarf variety too which you have called mexican petunia. They really resemble petunias.

Comment: Hi, Ratna! Morning glory and Mexican petunia are two different things. Morning glory is Ipomoea (family Convolvulaceae) and Mexican petunia is Ruellia simplex (family Acanthaceae).